# About HTML Navbar spaces

Tags: html, css

I don't have so much english to explain this but let's try it

I am new at html and Idon't know what

```
<nav class="nav">
        <a href="#" class="nav-item >Main</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-item" >main2</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-item" >main2</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-item">Special</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-item" >Admin</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-item" >Login</a>
        <span class="nav-indicator"></span>
</nav>
```

It's my code and I want to add spaces before Special
how can I do it?

thank you

[image]

Comment: Can you please add your CSS

Comment: Also, your HTML is invalid; there is a missing end quote for the `class` attribute on the first anchor tag (for "Main").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead doing the styling in HTML, you can add css code.

1. You may encapsulate the items for both groups with `div`, in order setting the space between the nav items and the logo with nav item, just change the number of `gap` and `margin`.

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav div {
  display: flex;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 15px;
  margin: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
    <div>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item" >Main</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item" >main2</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item" >main2</a>
    </div>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f4/BMW_logo_%28gray%29.svg/2048px-BMW_logo_%28gray%29.svg.png" width="40" height="40"/>
    <div>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item">Special</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item" >Admin</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item" >Login</a>
    </div>
 </nav>
```

2. You may just put it altogether and give some few lines for nav in css and they will evenly spaced. But it's not guaranteed the logo will be centered if the nav elements in the left and right side is different.

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
      <a href="#" class="nav-item" >Main</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item" >main2</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item" >main2</a>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f4/BMW_logo_%28gray%29.svg/2048px-BMW_logo_%28gray%29.svg.png" width="40" height="40"/>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item">Special</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item" >Admin</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item" >Login</a>
 </nav>
```

Comment: @helpmestuck Would you mind giving this answer an upvote? So it can help other users on the community

Answer (score 1):

you add space in many different ways

```html
  
   <nav class="nav">
        <a href="#" class="nav-item >Main</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-item" >main2</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-item" >main2</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-item" style="margin-left:22px;margin-right:22px;">Special</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-item" >Admin</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-item" >Login</a>
        <span class="nav-indicator"></span>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look here, and if you have any questions, please let me know in the comments down below.

I have used **flex** to aling items as you wish.
But I am not sure what your span item is for `<span class="nav-indicator"></span>` and how to display it property, so I will left it for you.

I have also used CSS logical property called `margin-inline`;

And I haved used it like this: `margin-inline: 2rem;` , it adds the margin on **left** and **right** sides, and it would be the same as:

```css
margin-left: 2rem;
margin-right: 2rem;
```

Please look at the snippet example or you can open an [external link](https://jsfiddle.net/UtmostCreator/cym7Ltq5/) and play with it for a bit

```css
.menu {
  padding-inline: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: row;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.menu__item-spaced {
  margin-inline: 2rem;
}

.menu__logo {
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-item">Main</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-item">main2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-item">main2</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item-spaced">
      <img class="menu__logo" src="https://www.fast.design/fast-inline-logo.svg" alt=""></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-item">Special</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-item">Admin</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-item">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
  <span class="nav-indicator"></span>
</nav>
```